# Convert list of dicts to multiple lists in one line

Tags: python

As the result of a query I receive an iterator where each row has two keys "x" and "y". From all the rows I want to extract a list with the x elements and the y elements.

Example data:

```
data = ({"x": 1, "y": -1}, {"x": 2, "y": -2}, {"x": 3, "y": -3})
```

What I want:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [-1, -2, -3]
```

Now I can just do a for loop:

```
x, y = [], []
for row in data:
    x.append(row["x"])
    y.append(row["y"])
```

Or something like this:

```
x, y = [b[0] for b in [list(a.values()) for a in data]], [b[1] for b in [list(a.values()) for a in data]]
```

But it seems to me like there should be a more elegant and straightforward way of doing this that I am not seeing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `zip` works and is kind of elegant, it may also be hard to understand to others, and relies on all the dicts listing `x` before `y`, *and* using a new-enough Python version that actually respects that order.

Alternatively, you may just use two list comprehensions directly reflecting your loop:

```
data = ({"x": 1, "y": -1}, {"x": 2, "y": -2}, {"x": 3, "y": -3})
x = [e['x'] for e in data]
y = [e['y'] for e in data]
```

Of course, you can also put them on the same line as `x, y = [...], [...]` if you prefer, or use a nested list comprehension for getting the values for both keys:

```
x, y = ([e[k] for e in data] for k in ("x", "y"))
```

Comment: Nice!  "Explicit is better than implicit."  -- [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possible solution using `zip`:

```
x, y = zip(*(x.values() for x in data))
```

If you want `x` and `y` to be lists (and not tuples):

```
x, y = map(list, zip(*(x.values() for x in data)))
```

You might also want to use the method proposed by @tobias_k (in my opinion, the cleanest one):

```
x, y = zip(*map(dict.values, data))
```

Comment: This relies on (a) all the dicts listing `x` before `y` and (b) Python respecting that order (which Python 3 does, but e.g. not Python 2)

Comment: Uhm, why `methodcaller` instead of `zip(*map(dict.values, data))`

Comment: @tobias_k OMG, you're absolutely right. Let me fix it

Comment: I am really not a fan of seeing `x` being used as a loop variable when it has nothing to do with the original `x`s in data and the final `x` list.

Comment: @Guimoute I was just using the same names the OP used. For clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = list(map(list, zip(*[d.values() for d in data])))
```

if the order of keys are not consistent in all dictionaries, to keep it one-liner:

```
x,y = ([x[1] for d in data for x in sorted(d.items())][i::2] for i in range(2))
```

Comment: The outer `list` call is useless ;)

Comment: you are right, I wanted to return a list rather than a map object. Thus the `list`. But perhaps if someone else wants a list of lists as return :)